# "too many indices" in single element array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm writing a code that starts by reading an input catalog given by the user. The catalog has a number of elements that goes anywhere from 1 o whatever. Then the code loops over all elements to do its thing.

Let's assume the names of the elements are stored in an array called "names"

When the catalog includes 2 or more elements, everything is fine. But when it includes just 1 element, I get the following errors:

```
len(names) --> len of unsized object
names[0] --> Too many indices for array
```

The code to read the catalog would be just

```
cat='cat.dat'
names=np.loadtxt(cat,unpack=True,skiprows=0,dtype=("U25"))
len(names)
print(names[0])
```

with cat.dat being just

```
name1
#name2
```

Does anyone know what would be the right way of doing this? I'm right now transitioning from IDL to Python, and this seemed a very straightforward way of writing it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your post with the code you are using with code formating

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If shape is `()`, 0d, you can only index with `arr[()]`, an empty tuple of indices. Or use `arr.item()`.

Comment: So, if I define a loop that goes from 0 to `len([names])` and at each step `print(names[i])`, I have to explicitly make an exception for the 1-element case?

Comment: You, and your code, should pay attention to the shape and dimensions of the loaded array.  Usually `loadtxt` is used to load a table like csv file, not a single string.  In that case it returns a 2d array (or 1d structured array).  You don't need `unpack` here, though that isn't causing problems.

Comment: If you are simply reading strings from a file, consider using a plain Python file read.  You don't need the extra baggage of `loadtxt`.

Comment: I'm reading a multi-column had-written table, with several columns of different datatypes and irregular spacing. The error happens when the catalogue consists in a single line (i.e. a single dataset to process). The example was the simplest case I could come up that reproduces the error. In reality each line of the catalogue would be something like `HD129926                F  0         14:46:00.1 -25:26:35.4     33.02  0.92      -151.50  -107.28  -17.20 5.29 4.94 `(with some more columns)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because a single element is loaded as a zero-dimensional array. You can convert `names` to a 1D array by calling

```
names = names.ravel()
```

or

```
names = names.reshape(-1)
```

If the array is already 1D (more than one element in the catalog) it will not be changed. (However, if the array has more than one dimension it will be flattened.)

Example:

```
x = np.array(5.0)
y = x.ravel()
print(y[0])  # 5
print(x[0])  # -> Error
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves it :) I knew it had to be something simple.